# Java: A good introduction to Java EE platform for noobs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

The question says it all; what are some good introductory resources for getting a good overview of the Java EE framework (preferably ones with examples)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For noobs?

http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/tutorials/

Struts + examples:

http://www.roseindia.net/struts/

Jstl + examples:

http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/1447551

Comment: Personally, I think roseindea has pretty poor tutorials.

Answer (score 6):

The [Java EE Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/tutorials/) is the best place to start.