# resources for .net programmer to learn Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: A good introduction to J2EE platform for noobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262366/java-a-good-introduction-to-j2ee-platform-for-noobs)

I'm not new to programming at all - I've programmed in .net for over a decade. I have dabbled now and then in java, but never at an enterprise level. Now I'd like to learn to use Java EE.

What are some good online resources, or books that I can buy? I'll need a step-by-step on what to download to set up my environment (I already have the Glassfish tools bundle for eclipse, but I'm not sure if this is what I need or where to go with it...).

I think coding a simple website to perform basic crud operations would give me a good start.

Comment: ... and if you aren't a "noob", you can gloss over the easy / boring bits.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, I'd stay away from anything that says J2EE as it's an outdated uglier version. Look for Java EE 6 or at least Java EE 5.

Apart from that my recommendation would be to download the [Java EE version of Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)
since it has everything you need. In the same site there [several starting tutorials and a longer e-commerce tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html)

If you want to start with Servlets and JSPs in Tomcat, just make sure it is selected during the install procedure.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising since I'm looking to download something all-in-one if possible. There are so many different downloades available.

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish is fine.  You might consider JBOSS as well; it's another Java EE app server that's open source and won't cost you a thing to try out.

I'm not sure if WebLogic from BEA/Oracle is still available to download for developers to learn, but it's my favorite Java EE app server.  Version 9/10 from BEA, before Oracle bought them, was simply the best.

You can start with a servlet/JSP engine like Tomcat or Jetty.  You would begin with servlets (HTTP listeners that respond to GET/POST requests); JSPs (a templating language using tags that are compiled into servlets and executed on the server - think of them as servlet/HTML factories); and JDBC (relational database connectivity).  You can go a long way with just those.

Once you've mastered those you can decide between a Java EE solution (EJBs) or Spring.  [Spring](http://www.springframework.org) is not part of the Java EE spec, but it's a fine alternative.  It's a combination of dependency injection, aspect oriented programming, and solid modules for persistence, remoting, messaging, web services, web MVC, LDAP, etc.

Comment: A small remark, EJBs are just as much POJO based as Spring beans are.

Answer (score 1):

The NetBeans IDE is not so ubiquitous as eclipse (so eclipse is a very good choice), but makes Java EE 6 with Java 7 and GlassFish very easy. And netbeans.org has several tutorials.